# is it possible to auto fill email field on external website?

Tags: html, javascript

**www.somesite.com**

```
 <form id="form_test" >
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    </form>

    or

    <div class="form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email1" value="" />    
    </div>
```

if that somsite have above code: is it possible to auto fill that email field via url like below

**www.somesite.com?email="test@gmail.com"**

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.

The extra information at the end of the URL is passed to the webserver but if the server side code is not specifically coded to handle it and to add it to the emitted HTML then you won't get the effect you desire.

Many browsers can auto-populate fields in forms, but you don't influence that by appending text to the URL.

Comment: yes you are right i know that that's why i wanted to know is there any possibility

Answer (score 1):

In a way... You need a plugin that can do this.

LastPass offers this functionality. You can use it to automatically fill in forms with your data.

Do note, it is not going to accept that from the url, but you can have it find that field and make the suggestion.

Some browsers also have this functionality, but they usually don't offer an autofill in the sense that you still have to click in the form somewhere and then select your profile to fill in all the fields associated with it. Vivaldi, a chrome based browser, does a great job in this regard.

My personal go-to for this kind of thing is still LastPass though. I load a website, and lastpass automatically fills it in as if the webpage comes with it by default.

Do note, if you are actually developing that website, then yes, it is very possible, but you have to build in support for this.

Comment: Actually that website what i am trying to access was not mine so how can write script to perform some action. what i want to know was just by using url how i can achieve that result,  if you know suggest me some link and also i am not looking for any plugin  i want to implement it

Comment: In php, you use $_GET['var'] and then in the addressbar, you can use ?var=something, and php knows what it is. You can use that in your html form to auto fill in stuff.